ToC for a journal volume
I am trying to make a small conference-paper volume for a local conference, and I am having some issues with Table of Contents part. I want to make it automatic, but can't figure out the syntax, googling for solution didn't get me anywhere. So far I have a custom .cls file that has the structure of each paper that needs to be submitted. Got it from Overleaf, I made it look what I want it to look like, and each individual papers submitted are okay. The next step is to group them together in a head file. I need ToC to look like this:
CONTENTS
1 Model Theory (in the center, so this will be a section but unnumbered)
then without numbering I want papers to appear the following way
Author 1, Author 2 (in bold)
Paper name .......1
2 Computability Theory
Author 1, Author 2
Paper name .......4
Key things in the .cls files are these I think:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\PassOptionsToClass{twoside,12pt,journal,a4paper}{journal}  
\LoadClass{journal}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T2A]{fontenc}

My approach was to make Model theory to be \section*{} and the \addcontentsline in the toc. but it didn't work. Then I found \journalpart{Model Theory} option and it looks good, but it doesn't appear in the ToC, I tried calling \journalcontents too, it didn't work either. I also would appreciate any suggestions on how to link papers to a section, for example model theory papers within Model theory \journalpart and so on. I use \input{paper} in sections, and everything seems to work fine. But maybe if I want to group them, I should use something different.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. The journal class on CTAN is part of paper, but is it this one, you are using?

@cabohah, not really sure about that. It's my first experience of doing something like this, so I just used this template from Overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/latex-template-for-preparing-an-article-for-submission-to-the-journal-bulletin-krasec-physical-and-mathematical-sciences-russian-template/sstpskhkdfsc

Papers are generally submitted as independt files, so combining them could be a problem.  Pdfpages loses links.  Subfiles loses preambles (\author etc.)  I doulbt journals give out their own internal software.

what language are the papers written in? you do not need inputenc unless your TeX install is a couple of decades old.

@cfr it uses english, russian, and kazakh. So sometimes I'm having problems with this part as well

@bheadr73 well, you probably want \usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc} or something so you have an encoding for english.
